Can a character in Ranma 1/2 be cursed multiple times?
The trope of Ranma 1/2 is that if you fall into a cursed spring in Jusenkyo, China, whenever you get doused with cold water you take on the physical attributes of whoever/whatever drowned in that spring so many years ago.  EG Ranma fell into spring of the drowned girl, his father Genma fell into the spring of the drowned panda, and Ryoga fell into the spring of the drowned black pig.
What would happen if any of these characters fell into a different cursed spring?  Would they be immune to a new curse? Or would they exhibit the attributes of multiple curses?

Pantyhose Taro is one of the most prominent examples.

Pantyhose Taro is a young martial artist who was born in Jusenkyo. Unfortunately for him, Happosai was visiting the cursed springs that day and decided, in a rare moment of altruism, to help the mother out with her birthing. Once he had the newborn baby in his hands, Happosai decided to bathe him and accidentally chose to use water from the most accursed spring in Jusenkyo: The Niuhōmanmaorennīchuan (Níuhèmànmáorénnìquán) or spring of drowned "yeti holding an eel and crane while riding an ox" (literally, "ox-crane-eel-hairy-man-drowned-spring"). Because of this, he transforms into a giant, winged minotaur-like creature when splashed with cold water. While others would consider it a tragedy, Taro in fact enjoys having the massive strength and power his cursed form grants him.

....

Later, Pantyhose Taro returned with a jar of water he thought was from the cursed spring of the drowned Samaritan. He planned to use that water to turn Happosai into a gentle old man who would be more than pleased to grant his wish of a new name. The water, however, was from the spring of drowned twins, which would have split Happosai in two. This mistake once again placed Pantyhose Taro at odds with Ranma, with the fight ending once Pantyhose Taro realized he had water from the wrong cursed spring. When they met again, Pantyhose Taro had added octopus tentacles on his back using one of the other cursed springs of Jusenkyo.

On the other hand, Ranma (and others) believes that him being doused in water from the Spring of Drowned Man will erase his curse. Instant Nannīchuan water does have that (temporary) effect on him. So, it would seem that the rules are not quite so clear-cut. It seems that Kiema was able to swap out her young girl transformation for one of a newly (almost) drowned Akane.

The Curses of Jusenkyo are all Spring-specific, as each spring is named after a specific transition trait. It appears that there can only be one spring per curse, or that no two have simply coincided. Regardless, the curses are all vastly different from each other and some may even defy common logic. There is at least one Spring where four animals were immersed in at once, and a few of them are apparently "Blank" in the regard that none of them have had anything "drown" in them yet.
One such spring was taken advantage of when Kiima used it to acquire Akane's self for her own use. Why it didn't just become another Spring of Drowned Girl further implies that only one spring will apply for the curse, but it is also possible that the other curses may simply turn the victim into the image of what drowned in there, but this does not explain why Pantyhose Taro's is a combination of an ox, yeti, eel and crane nor why Ranma's girl form is simply a genderswapped version of his male form (in the manga they are the spitting image outside of obvious gender build and the such, unlike the anime which has them with different hair colour, though in both incarnations their eyes are different). All other curse forms usually retain similarities to their original forms, whether discrete or obvious. In universe, Happosai could even recognize Genma from his eyes.


I read a lot of the manga in the late 90's but never got as far as Taro.  I'm now watching the anime on Amazon Prime and I think changing Ranma's build in the anime makes more sense than what they did in the manga.
